# Why php skips header(location:...) if no die; after it

Tags: php, if-statement, behavior

My code looks like this

```
if (...) {

   if(check_if_already_done()) {
      header("location: home.php");
   };


   do_it();
   header("location: done.php);

}
```

in this case even if already done returns true its going to done.php instead of home.php but when i add die; after header("location: home.php"); it does go to home.php
can someone explain why? It has to do with finishing main IF before doing header even if that header is at the end of nested if?

Answer (score 4):

even after the first  header() is called php keeps processing, so it reaches the 2nd header call a few millsecounds after the first and runs it.

and the location should be an absolute url.

Comment: Indeed, if it wasn't obvious, you generally want to terminate your scripts execution after issuing a header redirect, i.e., exit(0);

Comment: +1 for the absolute URI reference. Seems nobody does this. There's absolutely no guarantee how the client will treat a relative location header URL

Comment: When you build site on one server and then transfer to other its important to keep the, universal. I never had problem just file name in header.

Ok i did not know about that, seems like answer was on PHP manual, you can still have it full url but with using php function.

"HTTP/1.1 requires an absolute URI as argument to » Location: including the scheme, hostname and absolute path, but some clients accept relative URIs. You can usually use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and dirname() to make an absolute URI from a relative one yourself:"

Comment: @Phil: Since `HTTPbis` permits relative paths now, it's likely that all current user-agents have been supporting non-absolute URLs.

Comment: i always use absolute paths, for the multi-server issue, one of the defined vars i have on all sites is the site root url, makes this sort if thing easy.

Comment: @mario It's pretty much "always" worked, I'm just a stickler for protocol

Comment: the exit after header is very very important. this is the kind of problem so tiny but if missed could cause unintended behavior, could take you time to debug if you never noticed the header-exit partnership. been there done that. and learned the lesson to always write exit after header location